# duplicate meta descriptions and title tags

Tags: codeigniter, seo, meta-tags

I have a wallpaper site online , in order to optimize SEO,
webmaster tools marks 29 duplicate meta descriptions and title tags.

Whenever i click on a menu or submenu link , for example, "computers", i would like the title, meta description , title tags, keywords, to be updated to reflect the term Computer.

an important fact is that when i click on the menu , data is loaded asynchronously on the content div.

my website :
  http://www.fondolandia.com

I think i should start updating the Url when i click on a menu item, then updating the title, and meta data using jquery , would it help improve search results?

thanks in advance

[update]

i found this sample in another site, it seems to help in the search results.

[image: site updating title and description tags]

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to change the keywords (title, metadata, etc) when you click a menu item, right? If so, then doing so will not help in SEO the least bit, since search engines don't click on your links. They don't handle client-side events, they just look at the text present, where it is present, and what links to follow.

Comment: thanks cryptic, then how could i get something similar to what you see in the image i uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must create that pages for google indexing and then do whatever you want for users.